# Android App Crashes- When using a method to display integer

Tags: java, android

When I try to run the code it just crashes. Before I was using:

```
myTextView.setText(Counter)
```

Which was working but now when I try to make it easier and more efficient it does not work by using a method. Why?

I am trying to make a tycoon app and so I want to use a method so it is easier to display the amount of money the user has when they are playing the game. In the method, it would be much cleaner to make calculations.

```
package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private Button myButton;
    private int Counter = 0;
    private Button myButton2;
    private TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Counter = Counter(Counter);
                Display(Counter);
            }
        });

        myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Bundle store = new Bundle();
        store.putInt("count", Counter);
    }

    public int Counter(int Counter) {
        Counter++;
        return Counter;
    }

    public void Display(int Counter) {
        myTextView.setText(Counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a mistake in your code probably in this:

```
public void Display(int Counter) {
    myTextView.setText(Counter);
}
```

Try change to:

```
public void Display(int Counter) {
        myTextView.setText(String.ValueOf(Counter));
}
```

Comment: In the set text can you only use a string. Is that why it was wrong?

Comment: yeas, if you need to display numbers you need to convert to string using String.ValueOf() method. Every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To set text on TextView you have to use setText() method
And this method takes string as a parameter
So 
You have to parse **int to string**

Answer (score 0):

Above all the answer are correct, that if we give String value to the textView it will work fine, so giving int value to the text view is wrong.? Answer is **No**

Then what the root cause?
The reason is, if you set int value, it will consider as the resource id (see the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))), so it will try to find the relevant resource. mostly it will not find any value, it will give resource not found exception.

How we can solve this issue,
If you are sure that the value is not the resource is, just convert int value to string, and set it to the TextView it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

just use `myTextView.setText(Counter+"");`

`setText(int)` - > this method finds string from resource.